# Firefox new-tab add-on showing empty page when browser start

Tags: flutter, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I recently created a new tab add on with flutter. The add on works fine on Chrome. However, on Firefox there are 2 issues and this is one of them:

- The 1st new tab when Firefox start, depends on your settings, is either blank/empty or Firefox original new tab page. Subsequent new tab will use the add-on as it should.

I checked/installed other Firefox new tab add-on and they open on first tab. This does not happen in Chrome either.

Anyone have clue why this happen? Or fix?

Firefox add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pin2me/

Chrome add-on: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin2me/hclokpdkmfceobbckckjkdohdgeljlld

Repo: https://github.com/J-Siu/pin2me

PS: There is one more issue but will open a new post.

PS: Using web-ext or installing from Firefox add-on page, the first tab show complete empty in console.:

[image]
[image]

Its like there is no 'new tab' add on at all. But the next tab will see the add-on.

Comment: Debug the problem: https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/debugging/

Comment: @wOxxOm That was all done before I even post. The first tab has no error, no message in console at all. Just empty.

Comment: Check the extension's other consoles in about:debugging as shown in the link I gave. BTW it may be a bug in Firefox because its MV3 support is not yet finished. It seems you're trying to use service worker to generate the page so the workaround would be to get rid of it and generate the page in its own script.

Comment: Well, there is really not much to see in about:debugging. Regarding service worker, it is generated by flutter. Oh well, if it really FF bug, I properly just wait. I am waiting for the favicon api also, lol.

Comment: One more clarification. When compile for extension, it is not using service worker, the file flutter_service_worker.js is not used ata ll and I am deleteing it from the update version.